# pick_event seems to return the wrong index

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3D scatter plot using Matplotlib and Python. My goal is to highlight a point if it has been clicked.
Theoretically, the documentation shows exactly what I want: [Simple Picking Example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/event_handling.html). Also, I've seen several StackOverflow questions regarding this functionality. However, the on_pick function seems to return a wrong index.

I use a slightly adapted version of the [Simple Picking Example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/event_handling.html) of the documentation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

points_3d = np.random.rand(10, 3)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

scatter = ax.scatter(points_3d[:, 0], points_3d[:, 1], points_3d[:, 2], picker=True, c='blue')

def onpick(event):
    if event.artist != scatter:
        return
    n = len(event.ind)
    if not n:
        return
    for dataind in event.ind:
        pt = points_3d[dataind]
        ax.scatter(pt[0], pt[1], pt[2], c='red', marker='D', s=100)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return True


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

The resulting behavior is the following:
[image]

Why is the index of `pick_event` not corresponding to the correct 3D point?

Comment: In Windows 10 your problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to have been a known bug. I was using matplotlib v3.5.0 and upgrading to v3.8.1 fixed it.